# How to remove the shortcut arrow on Desktop using WiX?

Tags: wix

I recently moved to WiX for our installer. It seems to work fine, however I am having a small issue with the desktop icon. If I create an Icon, I always get the small Arrow in the left lower corner on the icon.

[image: Screenshot]

I use the following code to create the icon. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
<Component Id="xxx" Guid="{xxx}">
          <File Id="filxxx" KeyPath="yes" Source="Application.exe" >
            <Shortcut Advertise="no"
                         Id="MyProductDesktopShortcut"
                         Directory="DesktopFolder"
                         Name="My App"
                         WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
                         Description="Application"
                         Icon = "AppIcon">
              <Icon Id="AppIcon" SourceFile="Snowflake.ico" />

            </Shortcut>
          </File>
        </Component>
```

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wix or any installer tool have nothing to do with that arrow unfortunately, it's a Windows "feature" to be able to distinguish shortcuts. 
So you are not doing anything wrong, your setup is just fine.

But if you want to get rid of it on your computer then open regedit, go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > lnkfile,  delete IsShortcut registry value and restart.